# MongoDb River for Elasticsearch missing data

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

- Elasticsearch version: 1.4.4
- MongoDb version :
- Mongodb River version : 2.0.7

I have been successfully able to get a river established between Elasticsearch and MongoDB. The MongoDB has 3 collections, and I specified in my river to get data only from one collections. 
I do a count in mongodb to find out how much data exists in the collection (there are 8M+ docs). I create the river and let it run. Once its done running, I select the count in Elasticsearch. (the way I call it is done is when no docs are being indexed in more than 5 minutes). The count is approximately 3.+M

My question is: Is there something in Mongodb Oplogs thats preventing all of the data or is there some other cause ?

The trace logs show no errors being printed to the logs.

any idea what might be happening ?

Thanks
Ramdev

Comment: Wrong place to ask. Better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: can you share the steps followed for configuration